# DelegatingHandlers not executing when routes not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on a WebAPI 2 project which currently uses attribute-based routing exclusively, to the point that there are no routes defined in registration, and everything is working as expected.

However, I am now adding a `DelegatingHandler` to provide a heartbeat that I can ping with a HEAD request:

```
public class HeartbeatMessagingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (IsHeartbeat(request))
        {
            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Head)
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent) { Content = new StringContent(string.Empty) };
                var task = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                task.SetResult(response);
                return task.Task;
            }
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private static bool IsHeartbeat(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return request.RequestUri.LocalPath.Equals("/Heartbeat", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

However, the handler is not being invoked if I make the expected `HEAD http://localhost/heartbeat` request; if I call any route that does exist then the handler is invoked; and if I add an old-school routing configuration then the handler is invoked on the expected `/heartbeat` endpoint.

So, using attribute routing only, how can I handle a request to a "virtual" endpoint?

**Update**

The message handlers are registered as follows:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new HeartbeatMessagingHandler());
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new RequestAndResponseLoggerDelegatingHandler());
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ApplicationInsightsMessageHandler());
```

so it is registered before e.g. my global logging handler, and according to my understanding, message handlers receive messages in the order that they are registered.

Comment: Have you tried adding the handler earlier in the handlers? Show WebApiConfig.

Comment: Do you have "[Route("Heartbeat")]" Action somewhere in the project?

Comment: @Bikram no I don't have an action; I implemented this as a DelegatingHandler because I specifically did not want to create controllers/actions for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Nkosi I have updated the question to provide that information

Comment: Similar to how I did it in my example I would insert the handler at index 0 after I have already added my other handlers in case it got displaced while adding the others. I tested it in integration tests and the handler was getting invoked every time.

Comment: As a quick test. debug you register method and see if any handlers already exist in the collection before you add the heartbeat handler.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your handler is too late in the pipeline and a handler higher in the pipeline is short-circuiting the request before it reaches your handler.

consider inserting your handler higher up so it has a better chance of intercepting the request

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // add to the front of the pipeline
        config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new HeartbeatMessagingHandler());
    }
}
```